# Is Rails model class variables singleton across all the Unicorn instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Say I have a model and 10 running unicorn instances.

```
class Product
   @@name = "AAA"
end
```

Then I started an Rails console in the same environment to update this value.

```
Product.name = "BBBB"
```

Now the value is "BBBB" in all the Unicorn instances?

It seems that this is true but I want a solid confirm to this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, workers each load a private copy of their app. So when one unicorn worker changes the value of the class instance variable, others can't see it

Comment: I couldn't find a documentation for this. But this is something i have experienced in my project. See the answer on this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785108/how-do-i-store-access-update-a-thread-safe-variable-in-an-sinatra-app-unicorn

Comment: Cheers, just wanted to check if building code based on this answer would take me down the path to race condition debugging hell :-)